# How to call after_update callback for a particular column updation?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I have one model called points and in that i have 2 columns named clicked_at and opened_at. Those two columns will not be entered while creating record. Both the columns will be updated manually. Now i want to call a callback only for updating clicked_at column. Is there any way to do this? Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check it manually.

```
def my_callback
  if clicked_at_changed?
    clicked_at_did_change
  end
end

def clicked_at_did_change
  # do stuff
end
```

Comment: its not working. its not going inside the method itself.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What did you try, what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

for this ..[observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) will be a good option and there are many options when you want to call your code..while updating/creating/deleting/editing/saving ...it goes on.

```
class PointObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

##this method will be called everytime AFTER you update point object
   def  after_update(point)
    point.clicked_at =Time.now
    point.opened_at =Time.now
    point.save!

   end

end
```

**enable this observer in application.rb**

```
# Activate observers that should always be running.
    config.active_record.observers = :point_observer
```

You can do whatever you want and also you have many callbacks such as before_save,before_update..etc.
Moreover you can place all your observers in `app/observers/`..